# How can I feed data files of different sizes to a CNN?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have 5022 data files. I want to feed them into a CNN model.

However, the lengths of data files vary from, say, 50 to 1015 rows (the number of columns is constant).

In the case of image files, we can resize or downsample. However, the files I am working with are not image files.

What options do I have to feed those data files into CNN without losing any information?

I am thinking about padding the smaller files with zero.

Would that be a good idea?

Crossposted: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/42634/how-can-i-feed-data-files-of-different-sizes-to-a-cnn

Comment: You could also have multiple input layers for your model which connect to the same internal layers. You then jointly train on small and large inputs. It is possible that you would then have internal layers trained to perform well on both image sizes

Comment: Could you please say more about what these data files are? Does each one correspond to its own outcome the way that each MNIST digit could be sved as an individual data file (perhaps a $28\times 28$ CSV), each of which corresponds to an outcome (the digit in the case of MNIST)?

Comment: @Dave, Each file represents a protein. Contains various protein measurements as features.

Comment: Why don't they have the same features? Different numbers of amino acids? $//$ I thought people were using graph neural nets for deep learning protein analysis, specifically to let the message-passing layers extract features of common lengths despite the proteins not having the same size.

Comment: @Dave, They have the same features. I.e., number of colums is same. number of rows differs.

Comment: Why do the number of rows differ? What do the rows represent?

Comment: @Dave, *Why do the number of rows differ?* --- Lenghts of proteins differ.

Comment: @Dave, *What do the rows represent?* --- Relative distances of alpha-carbons along the chain.

Comment: So then it sounds like each row-column coordinate constitutes a feature, kind of like how  a vector time series with four features of length $100$ has $400$ pieces of information (features).

Comment: @Dave, You are mostly correct.

Comment: Okay, so you're essentially looking at time series of variable lengths (or images of varying sizes). Various techniques exist for handling such data. Fully convolutional neural networks can handle such images. If you want to think sequentially, various recurrent architectures could work. If you think of the folded protein as a network of iteractions between amino acids, a graph neural network seems reasonable, as the message-passing layers of the graph neural net create feature vectors of a uniform size. I believe one of the seminal GNN papers even dealt with proteins.

Comment: @Dave, I have one file for each protein. Hence, my professor told me to use CNN. If I use time series, that may come at a later stage of experimentation.

Comment: So a fully convlutional network it is, it seems.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, I am skeptical of doing serious deep learning work with only $5022$ observations. If you just want to learn the mechanics of preparing the data and doing the implementation in a package like TensorFlow or Torch, then that's fine.

Comment: @Dave, We have culled 5022 proteins, and that is what we have at the moment.

Comment: I believe you, yet that's still a rather small sample size for a deep learning approach.

Comment: @Dave, `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`